# Steam WindowsPhone 8 App

Tags: 8.0

Is there any Steam application for WindowsPhone 8? I have seen it for Android and iOS. Please let me know if there's any.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it has to do with finding out if a particular type of app exists.

Answer (score 2):

A quick google search *(all I searched for was "steam app windows 8 phone")* brought me to the [Windows Store](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/steam-center/8a449b8b-074c-4cb2-b0ce-420062be1b84) where there is a Steam app for download. It does work on the Windows 7.5 and Windows 8 platform.

Comment: That's not the official app!

Comment: @NeilTurner the poster asked if there was "any" application. There is actually 2 of them that I found right away. I never said it was an the official app from Steam, I was providing what the poster asked for.

Comment: In that case, the user is very lazy and this question should be closed.

Answer (score 2):

A quick search in the Windows Phone Store will reveal "Steam Center" by DG-InfoTec as the first search result. There are numerous other third-party apps available as well.

If you want an official app, contact Valve.

I'm new here, so can't comment or vote up comments yet, but +1 for off-topic by karancan. Even if asking if an app exists is OK, it doesn't take a lot of effort to search the store yourself before asking.

Comment: Thanks for the +1 :) but I will have to flag your answer as not an answer!

Comment: Eh, I suppose that's fair, since it looks like C-dizzle and I came up with the same answer - though our sources differed (google vs. the Windows Store). I'll cry, but I think I'll get over it.

Comment: Perhaps you would like to chime in on this post http://meta.windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/191/what-about-change-the-faq-allowing-question-about-apps . Your input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @row1 I would love to chime in - still working for those all important reputation points >.< I'll keep an eye on it and when I have the rep I'll add my 2 bits.